Why isn't $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X))\to (X,O_X)$ a closed immersion of LRS for all closed $Z\subset X$?
Let $(X,O_X)$ be a locally ringed space, and let $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ be the (topological) inclusion of a closed subset $Z$ in $X$.
Is $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X))$ a locally ringed space? I think that it should be so, as $i^{-1}(O_X)$ is a sheaf of rings, and for any $z\in Z$ there is an isomorphism $O_{X,z}\to (i^{-1}(O_X))_z$, so it is locally ringed too.
In this case, we have a morphism of locally ringed spaces: $$(i,i^\#):(Z,i^{-1}(O_X))\to(X,O_X)$$ using as $i^\#:O_X\to i_*(i^{-1}(O_X))$ the morphism given by the adjunction. Is this morphism a closed immersion? I think that it should be so because $i$ is a closed (topological) immersion and $i^\#_z:O_{X,z}\to (i^{-1}(O_X))_z$ is surjective (bijective in fact) for any $z\in Z$.
However if I try to calculate the ideal subsheaf $I\subset O_X$ associated to such closed immersion I get the zero subsheaf, that corresponds instead to the identity $(X,O_X)\to (X,O_X)$. So if $Z$ is not all $X$ this is surely a contradiction, meaning that I'm wrong somewhere. I'm thinking about this since yesterday but I can't figure it out, I hope you have some suggestion.
EDIT
A morphism of LRS $$(f,f^\#):(Y,O_Y)\to (X,O_X)$$ consists of:

a continuous map $f:X\to Y$;
a sheaf morphism $f^\#:O_X\to f_*(O_Y)$ such that, for any $y\in Y$,  the induced ring map $f^\#_y:O_{X,f(y)}\to O_{Y,y}$ is local.

Then $(f,f^\#)$ is a closed immersion if:

$f$ is a (topological) closed immersion;
the ring map $f^\#_y$ is surjective for any $y\in Y$.

Today I managed to think sporadically to the problem, the only conclusions that I could think of are the following:
(Let $(X,O_X)$ be a LRS)

Given the inclusion $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ of a closed subset $Z$ in $X$, then $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X))$ is in fact a LRS, and $(i,i^\#)$ is a closed immersion ($i^\#:O_X\to i_*(i^{-1}(O_X))$ is obtained by the adjunction).
The ideal sheaf $I:=\mathrm{ker}(i^\#)$ has the property that $I_x=O_{X,x}$ if $x\notin Z$, and $I_x=0$ otherwise.
The contradiction arises when $(X,O_X)=(\operatorname{Spec} A,O_A)$, and hence $Z=V(\mathcal J)$ for an ideal $\mathcal J\subset A$. Unless $Z=X$, there are no ideals $\mathcal I\subset A$ such that $\mathcal I_p=0$ for all prime ideals $p\supset \mathcal I$, and $\mathcal I_p=A_p$ for the prime ideals $p$ not containing $I$.
The latter point can also be used to see that, in case $(X,O_X)$ is a (not affine) scheme, then $\mathrm{ker}(i^\#)$ cannot be quasi coherent unless $Z=X$; hence $(i,i^\#)$ can actually be a closed immersion of LRS, but $(Z,i^{-1}(O_X))$ is not a scheme.




I can probably answer this question but need some clarification here. (1) What is your definition of a closed immersion in LRS? (2) How do you define the ideal sheaf $I$? (3) Please show us your calculation of $I=0$. (4) Please explain why this is a contradiction. (I find these points are necessary because we are in the category LRS and most of this is only well-documented for the category of schemes.)

But let me give you already a hint: What is the structure sheaf on $V(I)$? Is it really $i^{-1} O_X$? (The answers can be included in your edit.)

@MartinBrandenburg I have added more info in an edit, let me know what you think about it! Anyway I started thinking about this problem exactly because of your hint: the structure on $V(I)$ is not $i^{-1}O_X$, but I thought that $(V(I), i^{-1}O_X)$ was a closed subscheme, and it seemed strange that $(V(I), i^{-1}O_X)$ was isomorphic to $\operatorname {Spec} A/J$ for some $J$ such that $V(I)=V(J)$. But now I think that $(V(I), i^{-1}O_X)$ is a locally ringed closed subspace, just not a subscheme.

Almost everything you wrote is correct. Just your definition of a closed subscheme (or LRS) is wrong. You may have noticed this already when you wrote "(bijective in fact)". So basically you just need to look up the definition. Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352513/definition-of-closed-subscheme

@MartinBrandenburg but aren't my definitions those of Liu, Algebraic Geometry? I post the screenshots of the definitions we are talking about, they are at page 37-38

Sorry I mean the closed subscheme associated to a sheaf of ideals. Please check the linked question / duplicate as well.
